# Visualizing difference between two variables effectively

Tags: r, data-visualization

```
dat <- data.frame(decade = c("1950-1960", 
                             "1960-1970",
                             "1970-1980",
                             "1980-1990",
                             "1990-2000"),
                  population_diff = c(500,
                                      250,
                                      275,
                                      400,
                                      405))
plot(dat$population_diff, xlab = "Decade",
     ylab = "Difference in Population", 
     xaxt = "n")
axis(1, at= 1:5, labels = c("1950-1960", 
                             "1960-1970",
                            "1970-1980",
                            "1980-1990",
                            "1990-2000"))
```

I have a data.frame of the decades from 1950 to 2000 and their corresponding differences in population.

```
>dat
     decade population_diff
1 1950-1960             500
2 1960-1970             250
3 1970-1980             275
4 1980-1990             400
5 1990-2000             405
```

That is, 1960's population has 500 more people than 1950. 1970's population has 250 more people than 1960, and 500 + 250 = 750 people than 1950. The population sizes increases over time, and the year 2000 has the highest population: 500 + 250 + 275 + 400 + 405 = 1830.

[image]

I plotted the data.frame as is, and I feel like this is not the most effective way of visualizing the information. What are some other possibilities?

Comment: You can use `ggplot` i.e `library(ggplot2);ggplot(dat, aes(x=decade, y = population_diff)) + geom_point()` or use `ggplot(dat, aes(x=decade, y = population_diff)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")` for better visualization

Comment: One improvement could consist in changing the limits of the `y` axis. Since the plot shows *differences*, it would be useful to set the scale such that it starts at zero if there are no negative values. This could be achieved in your case with an additional parameter `ylim = c(0,max(dat$population_diff))` in the `plot()` command.

Comment: Additionally, one may consider plotting relative changes, expressed in `%`, instead of absolute values. This could provide a more intuitive information concerning the relevance of the changes than the absolute differences. In that case, however, it should be clarified within the y axis label or the plot title whether the relative differences refer to an initial population number or to the one of the previous decade; else the data is ambiguous and could be misinterpreted.

Comment: I don't understand how a population size can be specific for a decade. Is that the mean for the decade? I would plot the actual population size. If you don't have that, I would probably plot increase since the 1950s. However, I don't know what you want to illustrate with this. The most important question when designing a plot is what point you are trying to make/support with it.

Comment: I've edited R out of the title. As this is now on Cross Validated, how to do any graph in R is secondary. Indeed. illustrations using other software could be in my view be entirely appropriate. So far, exactly how to do it in any serious software is not a challenge, and the central issue remains what works best.

Answer (score 2):

Often people are relaxed about the differences between point and interval data. If I have a hundred annual rainfall totals, in principle they are for intervals not points, and there is a strict logic to showing one hundred bars with width 1 year and height each rainfall total. But in practice, a line chart is likely to be cleaner and clearer and thus preferable. In a bar chart of such data a lot of ink is used to no purpose and the convention of showing base zero for each bar can just be distracting. The same kind of logic often applies to showing the income or profits of firms in successive years, and in many other such examples.

But in this example changes over decades manifestly are for relatively long intervals compared with the series length. Showing such changes by point symbols is puzzling and challenging to decode as well as being strictly illogical, so I agree with @Eoin in recommending (touching) bars as a possibility.

My major suggestion is yet different. Changes in population are almost always easier to think about as % changes. Indeed, it is often best to show populations too. A logarithmic scale for population versus time has the special virtue that periods of constant, increasing or decreasing growth rates plot distinctly as linear, convex down and convex up segments.

If your readership is likely to be unfamiliar with logarithmic scales, that will be a detail to think about.

It is not clear whether the data given are real data or the entirety of your data, but even if they are, I suggest that this thread is of more interest to others if pitched a little more generally.

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about using a bar chart instead? It can be done simply using `barplot()`

```
barplot(dat$population_diff, xlab = "Decade",
    ylab = "Difference in Population", 
    xaxt = "n")
axis(1, at= 1:5, labels = c("1950-1960", 
                        "1960-1970",
                        "1970-1980",
                        "1980-1990",
                        "1990-2000"))
```

That will give you the varying population across the decades in a nice visual form

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's the purpose of summing up the differences. Anyway, added a new column ("x") in the data.frame, which sums the differences of previous decades. Plot code remain the same as that provided.

```
dat$x <- sapply(1:nrow(dat), function(x)sum(dat[1:x, "population_diff"]))
plot(dat$x, xlab = "Decade",
 ylab = "Difference in Population", 
 xaxt = "n")
axis(1, at= 1:5, labels = c("1950-1960", 
                        "1960-1970",
                        "1970-1980",
                        "1980-1990",
                        "1990-2000"))
```

Comment: This answer could be improved by commenting on the advantages (or cons) of your approach, and including what the resulting graph looks like.